# Mold on bark mulch in a green house

Tags: identification

This has grown in a greenhouse built this year in North Vancouver, BC.  Any ideas what it is? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an assortment of brown moss, a slime mould commonly known as Dog Vomit fungus (Fuligo septica, common on wet wood chips) and white fungal filaments. https://wimastergardener.org/article/dog-vomit-slime-mold-fuligo-septica/

This sort of thing is practically inevitable in wet or very moist soil which contains pieces of wood even outdoors, but in a greenhouse, which is a largely closed, humid/damp and warm environment, it's even more likely. The soil and chips are far too wet - if/when it dries out, most of this will disappear, but some residual fungal activity will remain because of the presence of the bark chips; fungi are part of nature's  disposal system and break down wood. If the soil the chips are sitting on was not sterile (from a commercially bought bag of potting soil) then it will naturally contain some mycorrhizae which may occasionally produce toadstools/mushrooms, but mycorrhizae is an essential element of the soil and often critical to plant  growth, unlike the slime mould previously mentioned. Slime moulds are not particularly attractive, but are essentially harmless,though they are a sign of extreme damp.